# Can one disable a tab stop for a mat-icon in angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material for user to input a password. I also i have the toggle which allows me to show or mask the text input. This all works fine except i would like to find a way to remove the eye icon which changes the field from text to password from the tab order. Right now if i am in the input field and hit the tab my next stop is the mat-icon. Is there away to not stop on the mat-icon ?

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter your password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
    <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: The tabindex="-1" used to be used for that kind of thing. Add that to the icon and see if it works.

Comment: thanks adding that to the button did the trick

Answer (score 0):

In this case try to add the property "tabindex" to the mat-icon with value "-1".

{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}